# How to use CASE WHEN in PostgreSQL without adding values to aggregation and GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I need to take one timestamp if my condition is right and other value, if not.

I made such condition:

`CASE WHEN tr.type = 'deposit' THEN tr.timestamp::date ELSE tr.status_last_change_timestamp::date END AS timestamp`

But PostgreSQL requires to add `tr.type` to aggregate function or to GROUP BY:

`ERROR: column "tr.type" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

But that's impossible for me, because I need to take deposits and other transactions in one row of result of query.

How Can I make it? Thanks!

Table `tr` contains (e.g.): `amount, type, timestamp, status_last_change_timestamp`

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) [mcve]

Comment: Maybe I need to use smth except CASE ... WHEN. My aim is to get the different columns of table depending on condition

Comment: Just add this field into `group by` statement. That's all!

Comment: @MaciejLos, but that'll break logic of my query. I can't do that because it will take deposits and withdrawals in different rows, but I need them in one row

Comment: @jarlh, I added columns

Comment: You're wrong. Do NOT add `tr.type` field into `select` statement. Follow the instruction from error message and find out what happens...

Comment: You are using `tr.type`, `tr.timestamp`, and `tr.status_last_change_timestamp` in the expression. If these are not part of the `GROUP BY`, then they must be part of the aggregation. You may want somthing like `CASE WHEN MAX(tr.type) = 'deposit' THEN ...` or something like `MAX(CASE WHEN tr.type = 'deposit' THEN ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MaciejLos gave the solution. In such situation you just need to add `tr.type` (in my example) to `GROUP BY` without adding it to `SELECT`.

Comment: While this may be true in your situation, it is usually *not* the solution for "such situation" :-) You use `GROUP BY ___` to get one result row per ___ (e.g. per account or per account and year). If you want to add a column to your result, e.g. a transaction date, you *don't* want to add this to your `GROUP BY` clause, because then you'll no longer get the result rows you have decided for. Rather, you'll decide what to show exactly in your results and use the appropriate aggregation function. In my example: Which date? The last transaction date (MAX)? The first (MIN)? A list (STRING_AGG)? ...